# Using CSS Animation from static position to fixed position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, css-animations

I'm trying to build a photo galley so that when you press a photo, it overlays the website, and the background turns grey, and there is an animation of the photo turning big.

This is the animation:

```
@keyframes img {
  0% {
    position: static;
  }

  100% {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10%;
    left: 10%;
    margin: auto;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
  }
}
```

The problem is that css don't animate changing the position from static to fixed.
Is there a solution to this problem?

Tried calculating the location of the image. Did not work

Comment: _"Tried calculating the location of the image"_ - that is what you will have to do - so that you can _set_ a fixed position for the image to start the animation from, that visually matches its current _static_ position. _"Did not work"_ - that is a very useless statement, we can not help you based on that. You need to show us what you tried. [mre]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS-animations, **position** is not a Animatable Property.

If you want to see the list CSS-animations properties: [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transitions-1/#animatable-propertie)

However you can use JavaScript get the same effect.

**Edit** : Example
**HTML**

```
<div class="img-container">
  <div class="opened"></div>
  <img
    class="img"
    src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1108099/pexels-photo-1108099.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1"
    alt=""
  />
  <img class="img"
  src=https://images.pexels.com/photos/406014/pexels-photo-406014.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1"
  alt="" />
  <img
    class="img"
    src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/2023384/pexels-photo-2023384.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1"
    alt=""
  />
  <img
    class="img"
    src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1851164/pexels-photo-1851164.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1"
    alt=""
  />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.img-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 5%;
  }

  .img-container img {
    width: 35vw;
    height: 40vh;
    object-fit: cover;
    cursor: pointer;
   }

  .img-container .opened {
    position: fixed;
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 5%;
    display: none;
   }

   .img-container .opened.active {
     z-index: 100;
     display: inline;
     background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.424);
   }

   .img-container .opened img {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
   }
```

**JS**

```
const imgContainer = document.querySelector(".img-container");
const imgs = document.querySelectorAll(".img");
const openedDiv = document.querySelector(".opened");

const toggleImg = (e) => {
  // selecting the img inside opened div
  let clickedImgSrc = e.target.src;
  let imgElement = document.createElement("img");
  imgElement.setAttribute("src", clickedImgSrc);

  openedDiv.appendChild(imgElement);
  openedDiv.classList.add("active");
};

const closeTheOpened = () => {
  openedDiv.removeChild(openedDiv.firstChild);
  openedDiv.classList.remove("active");
};

imgs.forEach((img) => img.addEventListener("click", toggleImg));
openedDiv.addEventListener("click", closeTheOpened);
```

Comment: link to preview Codepen: [Link](https://codepen.io/ramejaayush/pen/jOYmLyQ)